# Plotly go.Bar : Add custom legend labels based on values

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a dataframe with positive and negative values in one column. I am using plotly barplot, and I'd like customize legend labels based on the value.

Here's a mock pandas DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [07-2020, 08-2020, 09-2020, 10-2020],
                   'Value': [3, -2, 4, -1] })

df["Color"] = np.where(df["Value"]<0, 'rgb(0,0,255)', 'rgb(255,0,0)')
df["Name"] = np.where(df["Value"]<0, 'Low', 'High')


    fig = go.Figure(

        data=[

              go.Bar(
                        x=df["Date"],
                        y=df["Value"],
                        color=df['Name'],
                        marker_color=df['Color']
                    ),

              ],

        layout=go.Layout(

        

            xaxis=dict(
                tickangle=60,
                tickfont=dict(family="Rockwell", color="crimson", size=14)
            ),

            yaxis=dict(
                title="Net Change",
                showticklabels=True
            ),

            barmode="stack",

        )
    )
```

How do I add legend labels `Low` when value is negative and `High` when positive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't sure if your legend label was a legend or an annotation label, so I added support for both. To annotate a bar chart, you can specify it in the text The display position will automatically determine the location. To add high and low to the legend, I created a high data frame and a low data frame and gave each a name. As a layout, we specify the tick positions and display names in order to arrange them in data frame order.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['07-2020', '08-2020', '09-2020', '10-2020'], 'Value': [3, -2, 4, -1] })

df["Color"] = np.where(df["Value"]<0, 'rgb(0,0,255)', 'rgb(255,0,0)')
df["Name"] = np.where(df["Value"]<0, 'Low', 'High')

df_high = df[df['Name'] == 'High']
df_Low = df[df['Name'] == 'Low']

fig = go.Figure(data=[
    go.Bar(
        x=[0,2],
        y=df_high["Value"],
        text=df_high["Name"],
        textposition='auto',
        name='High',
        marker_color=df_high['Color']
    ),],)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(
        x=[1,3],
        y=df_Low["Value"],
        text=df_Low["Name"],
        textposition='auto',
        name='Low',
        marker_color=df_Low['Color'])
             )
                
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis=dict(
        tickangle=60,
        tickfont=dict(family="Rockwell", color="crimson", size=14),
        tickvals=[0,1,2,3],
        ticktext=df['Date']
    ),
    yaxis=dict(
        title="Net Change",
        showticklabels=True
    ),
    barmode="stack",
)
    
fig.show()
```

[image]